# What font does the logo for East Photographic use?

Tags: font-identification

See the [website](http://eastphotographic.com) for the logo. I tried What the font, but it didn't recognize the "s" and "t". This might be custom vector work.

[image]

Comment: that line between the s & t is called a discretionary ligature, they appear between certain letter combinations in some fonts.

I've found a close similar that is free DejaVu Serif Book

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/DejaVu-Serif

Answer (score 9):

Looks like [Century Schoolbook Roman](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/bitstream/century-schoolbook/roman/) to me:

[image]

The swirl on the 'st' is a stylistic ligature that's common among typographers (and available in many OpenType fonts), but pretty rare in real-world use. The gap in the crossbar of the 't' is probably custom.

[Further reading on ligatures if you're interested](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographical_ligature).

Comment: Close, but not quite.

Comment: @DA01 Which glyphs in particular are you looking at? The 'E' does look a bit more rounded on the arms, but that could just be customization. The only real idiosyncrasy is the gap in the crossbar of the 't'. I now see that it's in the "Representing creative artists" bit as well, which could still be customized, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: Century has a lot of iterations. It's possible that it isn't that specific typeface, but I'm really confident that it's *some* kind of Century.

Comment: it's definitely close. It's certainly some variant of Century. The tail of the 't' is one difference, though. The original example has it going straight up while the stock Century has it flaring out to the up to the right ever-so-slightly.

Comment: @DA01 - I see what you're saying. And the more I look at that 'E', the more I see that it's just a touch different. Maybe I'll have to do some research on Century revivals!

Comment: Also, while watching the code (of the web page), you could see that this isn't in fact text but those are pictures (GIFs). I think, that increases the likelihood of the Font being customized...

Answer (score 2):

For "E" of "East" the font is Grad: http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/marksimonson/grad/

For the "ast" of "East" the font is Grad Alternate: http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/marksimonson/grad/alternate/

Comment: Nice find, but there's a whole bunch of little details in the logo (e.g. the serifs on the "s") that match Century Schoolbook better than any of the Grad variants. I'd say it's either some other derivative of Century Schoolbook that we haven't found yet, or just custom work based on it.

Comment: Mark does great work, but yea, that's not a match.

Comment: [Be kind, show a preview of the font please.](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2797/be-kind-show-a-preview-of-the-font)